# Почему вместо русских букв отображается Юникод и как это решить?

Tags: c#, json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Выполняю POST запрос на сайт, при получении текста вместо русских букв отображается Юникод.
Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp;

namespace balaboba
{
    class Program
    {
        public class post
        {
            public string filter { get; set; }
            public string intro { get; set; }
            public string query { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://zeapi.yandex.net/lab/api/yalm/text3";
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest();
            var body = new post { filter = "1", intro = "0", query = "Привет!" };
            request.AddJsonBody(body);
            var response = client.Post(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не надо это решать, это нормально, десериализируйте, получите нормальные значения.

Comment: Это `JSON`, в нём так и должно быть.

Comment: Потому что это разрешено JSON-грамматикой.